# Pass variable in soup.find() method - Beautifulsoup Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Currently, I'm searching for elements using the below syntax:

```
priceele = soup.find(itemprop='price').string.strip()
```

Actually, the page contains **`<span>`** element having attribute name `itemprop` with value `price`. But, I don't need to look for **`<span>`** element because there is only one element with attribute `itemprop`.

Now, what I want is to pass `itemprop='price'` as a variable to `soup.find()` method becausing I'm loading these two things from database dynamically. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. It did solved my issue. I used search = { row[0]: row[1] } where row[] is fetched from mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "two things" you refer to the name and value of the attribute, you can make them dynamic by using the `**` operator to apply arbitrary keyword arguments. For example:

```
attrname = 'itemprop'
attrvalue = 'price'
search = {attrname: attrvalue}

priceele = soup.find(**search).string.strip()
```