# How to pass to find()/find_all() a set of arguments as ONE long variable

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Say I have this html code:

```
html = """
<div non_class="first"></div>
<h2 style="some_style"> Text 1</h2>
<div non_class="second"></div>
<div non_class="first">Text 2</div>
"""
```

Using this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(html,'lxml')
```

I pass to `soup.find_all()` two arguments, a tag and a attribute/attribute value pair:

```
first = soup.find_all('div',non_class='first')
for i in first:
    print(i)
```

will output:

```
<div non_class="first"></div>
<div non_class="first">Text 2</div>
```

Simple enough. Now let's say that instead of hard-wiring the arguments, I want to pass them to `find_all()` as variables. Based on questions [such as this](http://[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075310/pass-variable-in-soup-find-method-beautifulsoup-python]), [this](http://[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53769439/beautifulsoup-pass-variables-in-soup-find]), [or this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45028533/pass-argument-to-findall-in-bs4-in-python]), I used this approach:

```
my_tag = 'div'
my_att = {'non_class': 'first'}

second = soup.find_all(my_tag,my_att)
for i in second:
    print(i)
```

And it produces the correct output. But this is far from satisfying. My 'target' tag is `<div non_class="first">` and (if everything works out) it will be one entry in a list of targets which I intend to use in a `for` loop. But the approach presented in those answers requires (unless someone has a better approach!) that I break the target into its components: first, a tag (in this example - `div`),  and then take the attribute/attribute value pair (in this example `non_class="first"`) and convert it into a dictionary (`{'non_class': 'first'}`) and feed those two into `find_all(_)`. It's doable, but inelegant.

So I tried to pass the whole set of arguments using one variable, but

```
target = '<div non_class="first">'

third = soup.find_all(target)
```

finds nothing. Using f-strings to feed the target:

```
fourth = soup.find_all(f'{target}')
```

also fails.

EDIT: To clarify, the purpose of the exercise is to feed the element to `find_all()` *without* having to decompose it first into its constituent parts, either manually or with the use of a helper function. Conceptually, I guess I don't understand why `find_all()` can take the element as a string argument directly, but if the string is assigned to a variable, `find_all()` can't take that variable and re-constitute it as a string argument...

So is it doable, or do I have to resign myself to slicing and dicing the target? Alternatively, can it be done with Selenium?

Comment: I don't see why that's problematic... You can break `<div non_class="first">` into small chunks, and construct the (list of) two arguments programmatically.

Comment: @renyuneyun - It's not really "problematic" as such; as I said - it's not elegant and feels non-pythonic, for some reason.

Comment: I don't know, but I don't think it's related to "pythonic" -- beautifulsoup just doesn't have the api to handle "search for all tags matches the semantics of *a string looks like a starting of a html tag*". And I doubt the need for beautifulsoup to have this api -- it should rather be a function to parse that string.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to extract the data. if i understand the use-case correctly below options might help you.

```
html = """
<div non_class="first"></div>
<h2 style="some_style"> Text 1</h2>
<div non_class="second"></div>
<div non_class="first">Text 2</div>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')


print(soup.find_all(non_class="first"))

find_element = lambda target,soup : soup.find_all(target['tag'],{target['attribute']:target['value']})
target = {'tag':'div','attribute':'non_class','value':'first'}
print(find_element(target,soup))

target = {'non_class': 'first'}
print(soup.find_all(attrs=target))

print(soup.find_all(non_class="first"))
```

Even you can implement something like below that will take html tag as string and returns target value.

```
def get_element(selector_string,soup):
    element = BeautifulSoup(selector_string,'lxml').body.next
    return soup.find_all(element.name,element.attrs)

print(get_element('<div non_class="first">',soup))
```

Comment: Your answer works, but unfortunately it doesn't address the actual issue: extracting the data is easy enough - the issue is how: I'll edit the question to clarify, but the idea is to do that without having to decompose the element into its `tag` and attribute pair components, either manual (like you did) or by using a function.